# Lane Detection for curved lines

Tags: python, c++, image-processing, opencv3.0, hough-transform

I am using `cv2.HoughTransformP` to do lane detection and it's working well.  But it fails when the road has curved lines

My sequence of steps for line detection is basic and goes as follows:

```
1. Grayscale image
2. Guassian Blur image
3. Canny Edge detect
4. HoughTransformP canny image
5. Calcualte average slope for left and right lane lines found
6. Extend average slope from point on horizon to edge of image (hood of the car)
7. Blend image 6 onto original
```

[image: example of algorithm working well]

[image: algorithm failing]

After some light reading, I'm seeing that`generalized hough` can do this.  The [OpenCV GPU](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/cudaimgproc/doc/hough.html#cuda-creategeneralizedhoughballard) modules have support for this but I do not have a GPU.

I did find a [tutorial](http://www.itriacasa.it/generalized-hough-transform/instructions.html) with `c++` code but before I get started down the path of creating a shared object, then calling it in python, I thought there might be a pythonic way to do this first.

So my question is: can I tune my steps and HoughTransformP params enough to fix the issue? Or do I have to use generalized Hough? If so, is there a way to do this in python?